# VB Basic no ejecuta .exe

Tags: vb.net, vb

Tengo un Launcher hecho en VB, que tiene que ejecutar un archivo .exe pero no lo hace. Y si creo un acceso directo a ese .exe y lo ejecuto si funciona. Pero no me sirve ya que el acceso directo no funciona en otras computadoras.

Asi es como lo ejecuto:

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "800x600" Then
        Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\data\resolucion.txt", False, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(437))
        sw.WriteLine("800")
        sw.WriteLine("600")
        sw.Close()
        Me.Hide()

        Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\Juego.exe")
    End If
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has depurado si `Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\Juego.exe"` apunta exactamente al sitio correcto?

Comment: Sisi, yaa que si coloco `Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\(Acceso directo al .exe)"`Funciona sin ningun problema

Comment: Has probado sólo poner `Process.Start("\application.windows64\Juego.exe")`?

Comment: Entonces,lo único que se me ocurre es que pueda ser un problema con el directorio de trabajo. Te he puesto una respuesta, prueba con eso y me dices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que el problema sea por no establecer el directorio de trabajo de la aplicación que quieres ejecutar. Intenta con este código:

Cambia:

```vb
Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\Juego.exe")
```

por:

```vb
Dim startInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\Juego.exe")
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath & "\application.windows64\ "
Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Comment: Asi me abre la carpeta, en que parte pongo para ejecutar la aplicacion?

Comment: @TuteeUnited Si,perdona,me falto poner `juego.exe`. Mira ahora la respuesta editada

Comment: Te ganaste el cielo, estoy desarrollando un proyecto final para cuarto año de la secundaria, en el que hay que realizar algun proyecto en Processing, pero con este launcher va a quedar hermoso. Gracias!